# VBA: Match Index function

Tags: excel, vba

I can't give you the Excel file I use, as it has a lot of confidential info, but I'll try to summarize the issue the best way I can.

I have a file A with a list of people that will start in a company, their start date, cost center... That file is sent daily, and has a lot more information that I need

I have a file B which we use to work on it, and to record all changes (like the start date), and all action done.

I managed to get a code that is working to update the file with the new names, without deleting the rest of it. I am now looking for a solution that will help me find out if the start date changes, what is the new start date, and create a comment in the file that the start date changed.

A simple Vlookup won't cut it, as the start date is before the name. So I compined the match & index function, and end up with this monster formula for the comment... I know it's not great, not least because I don't know how to get that part ([ABC.xls]Report'!R360C1:R440C10) to actually refer to the range I defined before, but it does the job for now.

But now, I have absolutely no idea how to get the new start date in the work file. Can you please give me your opinion?

Here is the part of the code that I did.

```
nR2 = Firstemptyrow()
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(INDEX('[ABC.xls]Report'!R360C1:R440C10,MATCH(RC[-23],'[ABC.xls]Report'!R360C2:R440C2,0),1)<>RC[-24],CONCAT(""WARNING, new start date is"", TEXT(INDEX('[ABC.xls]Report'!R360C1:R440C10,MATCH(RC[-23],'[ABC.xls]Report'!R360C2:R440C2,0),1),""jj/mm/a" & _
    "a""), "". Was changed from "", TEXT(RC[-24],""jj/mm/aa""),"" on "", TEXT(TODAY(),""jj/mm/aa"")),"""")" & _
    ""
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 25), Cells(nR2 - 1, 25)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("Y:Y").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Loop through column Y, if `<> ""` then make the `date` in `workbook B` equal to the `date` in `workbook ABC`.